# Wait for input from a textbox, similar to Console.Read()

Tags: c#, textbox, user-input

So I'm trying to have the user enter some input which derives its data from a class variable. The user will enter their input though a textbox and hit *return* when finished, causing the event to update the class variable. However, my issue is figuring out how to send a signal from the EventHandler to continue the process. I know a simple solution would be to put the code triggered inside the event method, but I want to use multiple methods with this textbox and input.

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private String input;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        outbox.AppendText("Hello World!"); //outbox is the display
        start();
    }

    private void inbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            input = inbox.Text; //inbox is the textbox for input;
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    private void start()
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Enter one, two, three or four.");

        //---
        //this is where the issue arises
        //---

        if (text_input.Equals("one"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Sunflowers");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("two))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Tulips");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("three"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Daisies");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("four"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Poppies");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("quit"))
        {
           Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Try again.");
           start();
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to pause the program until the user hits *return* and passes a string to `input`?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot move all the input comparison (checking if user entered 'one', 'two', etc) into the `inbox_KeyPress` event handler, after `input = inbox.Text;`? Alternatively, you could consider a 'submit' or 'go' button which would 'trigger' the input checking. Another possible (but ugly) way is `while(true) { if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) break;) }` (input or text_input, not sure which one is the right one)

Comment: Well, the reason I don't want to move the checks into `inbox_KeyPress` is because I want to be able to draw text from `inbox` to use in multiple methods. If I did put the conditions in the method, then it would call multiple methods every time it fired, and that wouldn't work in my scenario.

Comment: This is unclear. What is the program doing before the user presses *return* that you don't want it to do? A Windows Forms app is event-driven, so most of the time it's not doing anything except waiting for an event. So when you say that you want the program to "pause" I'm confused. Is it doing something before the event is triggered?

Comment: The program starts running the `start` method and gives errors since there's nothing in `input` or loops infinitely because there's incorrect input. I'm trying to get the Console.Read() type setup going, where it waits for user input before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably separate the actions **before** user input from actions that should happen **after** user input.

If you want to implement different behaviours then it may help to store the **program state**, including the action you want to perform after user input is complete.

Try something like this, and adapt as required:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private String input;

    private enum InputMode {
      None,
      Numbers
    }

    private class ModeDefinition{
      public InputMode Mode {get; private set; }
      public string Prompt{get; private set; }
      public Action ActionMethod{get; private set; }

      public ModeDefinition(InputMode mode, string prompt, Action actionMethod)
      {
          this.Mode = mode;
          this.Prompt = prompt;
          this.ActionMethod = actionMethod;
      }
    }

    private InputMode currentMode;

    private Dictionary<InputMode,ModeDefinition> modeDefinitions;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        outbox.AppendText("Hello World!"); //outbox is the display

        initialise();

        currentMode = InputMode.Numbers;
        commenceAction(modeDefinitions[currentMode]);

    }

    private void initialise(){

      modeDefinitions = new Dictionary<InputMode,ModeDefinition>();

      var def1 = new ModeDefinition(InputMode.Numbers, "Enter one, two, three or four.", numbersAction);
      modeDefinitions.Add(InputMode.Numbers, def1);

    }

    private void commenceAction(ModeDefinition modeDefinition){
      outbox.AppendText(modeDefinition.Prompt);
    }

    private void inbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            input = inbox.Text; //inbox is the textbox for input;

            var currentMode = modeDefinitions[currentMode];

            // Execute the mode action
            currentMode.ActionMethod();
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    private void numbersAction(){

        if (text_input.Equals("one"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Sunflowers");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("two))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Tulips");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("three"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Daisies");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("four"))
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Poppies");
        }
        else if (text_input.Equals("quit"))
        {
           Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
           outbox.AppendText("Try again.");

          var currentMode = modeDefinitions[currentMode];
          outbox.AppendText(modeDefinition.Prompt);          
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know my solution is what y need
Firstly , u declare property like this

```
private string _content;

private string content
{
    set
    {
        if (value != _content)
        {
            _content = value;

            checkContent();
        }
    }

    get
    {
        return _content;
    }
}




private void checkContent()
{
    if (content.Equals("one"))
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Sunflowers");
    }
    else if (content.Equals("two"))
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Tulips");
    }
    else if (content.Equals("three"))
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Daisies");
    }
    else if (content.Equals("four"))
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Poppies");
    }
    else if (content.Equals("quit"))
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Try again.");

        start();
    }
}

    private void start()
    {
        outbox.AppendText("Enter one, two, three or four.");
    }

    private void inbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            content = inbox.Text; //inbox is the textbox for input;
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```